# Add sorting to "no answers" tab on unanswered questions tab

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

If you go to a tag and click on the no answers unanswered tab, the results are sorted by answer count, but then after that they are listed in no apparent order (but a consistent non-order). So for a lot of popular tags, there are page after page of 0 answer questions in no other order.  It would be great if you could further sort these by something like date opened, like `order by voteCount, dateAdded desc`.

Comment: I would love to see sorting functionality as well!! Right now they seem to be sorted by vote count.  But I'd love to be able to order unanswered by date added instead. Maybe by querystring parameters or some UI element.

Comment: Views also proposed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161915/see-which-unanswered-questions-have-the-most-views