# See which unanswered questions have the most views

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, questions-tabs

It seems to me that the questions we would want most answered are the ones that are getting the most Google hits. I think that when you click on the "Unanswered" button on the home page instead of being in the "newest" tab you should by default be in a "most viewed" tab. This will call attention to questions that the most users want answered, so that people can answer them or close them as needed.

Comment: You already can search for questions *filtered* by a [minimum number of views](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160856/200500). Unfortunately, you can't sort by views, so this is pretty sorely needed.